# How do you prevent Visual Studio 2012 from closing IE when you stop debugging?

Tags: debugging, web, visual-studio-2012

When I was using Visual Studio 2010, I could just "Detach All" and the web site would continue to run and the browser wouldn't close. That would enable me to attach a different solution to debug a separately compiled library. Now all that's left is "Stop Debugging" and "Terminate All".

Although the website is still running in the background, I have to open a new browser window and navigate back where I was.

Is there some way to go back to the 2010 functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detach All is still available in VS 2012. If you don't have it under Debug in Main Menu then you may need to add it manually (right click on toolbar, select Customize.. from context menu).